# Is the following "which" descripting a singular subject or plural subject?

Tags: grammar

This is a correcing-gramatial-error question from the IELTS OG. the relavant picture is provided here[image]

Acccording to the answer, error No.10 "is extending" is replaced with "has been extended", which sounds incorrect to me.

In my view, the subject being described by "which" is " the supermarket and the hotel", so the correct answer should be "have been extended".

I would like a second opinion on this.

Comment: You can’t tell without the rest of the sentence, which probably speaks of building a new wing that accommodates more guests. How do you extend a supermarket and a hotel at the same time?

Comment: @Xanne There is a full stop at the end of "is extending." So there is no rest of the sentence.

Comment: There was no supermarket in the the 1700s, so that did not get extended. In general, we're not crazy about doing homework for others, not even for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is that only the hotel is involved with this extension, so a singular verb is used.  However, there's no clue as to whether the extension has been completed or is still on-going, so to say that "is extending" is wrong is bogus (though "is being extended" would be more idiomatic).

Apparently it's not unusual for an IELTS test to be bogus, though.

Comment: Perhaps the "two maps" give context for determining the tense of the hotel extension.